# background video appears on all my components

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

well I'm displaying a video in background and set it with this style and I put some text above it

```
.video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

the problem is what ever I want to put after the video on white background the video keeps scrolling wit the page ( so the video stays on all the web page)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `position: fixed` and add `margin: 0;` to remove that white space.

Answer (score 0):

@Unnat
I changed the style to this and I got the style I wanted , but I'm pretty sure this isn't the best practice

```
.video {
  position: absolute;
  width: 133%;
  height: 200%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: There is no need for any ```position: absolute```
and why you have done this to the width you can just do ```margin: 0;``` to remove the space

Comment: fixed the width mistake, and { position: absolute } because as I said before I put some text above the video, well thx man